# Microsoft Edge not visiting URL when being run by Protractor script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, microsoft-edge

I am building a set of Protractor scripts to evaluate the performance of a web app.

A month ago, the tests were running in both Edge and Chrome. I stepped away from the project for two weeks, and performed a Windows OS update on my return. Since then, when running the test in Microsoft Edge, I get alternating results between 1) an unknown error where the browser never even launches (I will post the cmd output from this result below), and 2) having the Edge browser open but not visiting the base URL it is supposed to (where I am getting a timeout error after being on the Edge homescreen for 10 seconds). I unfortunately did not have the opportunity to run the script before the Windows update, so I am not certain if that is the cause, but I think it is likely. The tests continue to run correctly when operating in Chrome.

I have tried reinstalling Edge's webdriver several times and have chekced its path. I would like to roll back Windows but think this would be a hassle with our IT department, so I am wondering if anyone has found a different solution to this problem?

This is the error when the browser fails to open:

```
\Browser Tests>protractor edge_conf
[13:32:48] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:32:48] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:17556
[13:32:48] E/launcher - Unknown error
[13:32:48] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Unknown error
    at WebDriverError (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:440:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:777:24)
    at createDriver (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:167:33)
    at Builder.build (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:632:14)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\driverProvider.ts:60:29)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\jarlan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
[13:32:48] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up pushing Windows to version 1703 (Build 15063.540), which was easier to get approved than rolling back.

After reinstalling the appropriate WebDriver, everything is working properly with Edge. Still unclear what was causing the problem, but this seems to have worked around it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the PM for WebDriver at Microsoft. It sounds like you need to get the proper version for your build of Windows.

You can find all the releases of WebDriver [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/). To see what build of Windows you have just hit [Windows Key] + [R] and type "winver".

Comment: Clayton, thanks for the response. I'd already tried reinstalling the WebDriver several times (and made sure it was the correct version with my version of Windows & Edge). I tried again but still having issues. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a local copy that's older somewhere (maybe in your bin) that's getting used instead of the new one? Or perhaps the old one is still on your PATH? Other than that I can't think of why it wouldn't work if you're matching versions. What version of Selenium are you running (although I don't know why that would affect it)?